# Magento error after Upgrade : Can't perform operation, incomplete metadata

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.12

I have updated version of Magento EE 12.2 to Magento 14.2.0.2 but i get error when update or create product and category. Error massage is **"Can't perform operation, incomplete metadata!"**

I have also tried ['Enterprise_Index_Model_Action_Exception' with message 'Can't perform operation, incomplete metadata!'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13322/enterprise-index-model-action-exception-with-message-cant-perform-operation) but not work for me.

Here is screenshot of error.
[image: adminerror]

```
2016-06-20T12:36:57+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Enterprise_Index_Model_Action_Exception' with message 'Can't perform operation, incomplete metadata!' in app\code\core\Enterprise\Index\Model\Action\Abstract.php:125
Stack trace:
#0 app\code\core\Enterprise\CatalogInventory\Model\Index\Action\Refresh\Row.php(69): Enterprise_Index_Model_Action_Abstract->_validate()
#1 app\code\core\Enterprise\Mview\Model\Client.php(123): Enterprise_CatalogInventory_Model_Index_Action_Refresh_Row->execute()
#2 app\code\core\Enterprise\CatalogInventory\Model\Index\Observer.php(53): Enterprise_Mview_Model_Client->execute('enterprise_cata...', Array)
#3 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1358): Enterprise_CatalogInventory_Model_Index_Observer->processStockItemSaveEvent(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Enterprise_CatalogInventory_Model_Index_Observer), 'processStockIte...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('cataloginventor...', Array)
#6 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(344): Mage::dispatchEvent('cataloginventor...', Array)
#7 app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item.php(893): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->afterCommitCallback()
#8 [internal function]: Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item->afterCommitCallback()
#9 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Abstract.php(110): call_user_func(Array)
#10 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(322): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->commit()
#11 app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php(728): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#12 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#13 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#14 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Comment: how to you update magento? I think you don't update database structure. You can try clear all cache and run `index.php` by command line on server `php -f index.php` for start new upgrade scripts.

Comment: @Naumov i have use this link for upgrade magento http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_details.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use php 5.3 disabling warnings and notices. It avoids some code warnings deprecation in old version.
If you get some invalid function name in the middle, go upgrading to 5.4, 5.5, etc.

It usually works for me. ;)